# Plotting multiple graphs of multiple types on 2 axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization

I am attempting to create complex plots where there are 2 data series on the left in the form of a bar graph and two data series on the right in the form of a line graph. 
Matlab conveniently provides the plotyy function which should do what I am attempting.

```
>> line=[linegraph1 linegraph2]  
>> bar=[bargraph1 bargraph2]
>> [hAx,hBar1,hLine2]=plotyy(dates,bar,dates,line,'bar','plot');
```

Executing this code gives me the following error.

```
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: You are shadowing the built in [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) and [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) functions with your variable declaration. Don't do this.

Comment: I would also recommend you provide the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: The variables are edited for clarity as the exact series that I am trying to plot aren't relevant as part of this discussion. Thanks for the feedback, will make sure not to do so in my actual code.

Comment: Providing example code that reproduces the issue as well as the entire error message is absolutely relevant to the discussion if you want someone to actually be able to help you. What you have provided doesn't replicate the error on my machine, even with the shadowing.